# Preview and PDF are not the same in Birt

Tags: pdf, margin, padding, birt, right-align

As you can see on the below image everything looks fine on PDF but on Web Viewer/Preview the numbers are not aligned nicely.

[image]

I don't understand this ... what can I do to display the numbers like in PDF form? FYI this is a column of a row of a table and the content is a **1x2 Grid**, has two data elements one in 1st column other in 2nd column. Both data elements are right aligned. I tried to fix this problem with padding the first element 30 from left but didn't help. I would be glad for your tips!

Comment: When you open as a web page (not in previewer) do you have the same issue or is this limited to just preview?

Answer (score 0):

The Previewer tends to offer less then optimally formated or fully functional design.  Open the report in the format/tool that will be used in the final delivery for true testing durring design.  Personally I have Apache on my test server and do all of my preview testing as a web page.

**Edit** based on comments

I don't recall ever seeing anything like this occur.  If you create a new report using the sample data base, do you get the same issue?  If no, then you have something off on this report, it might be easier to create a fresh report, without the issue.  If yes can post your report with example data at http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/forum/2-designing-birt-reports/ so others can see if they see the same issue.

Comment: Web Viewer and Preview both have the same result, what is important for me is the PDF and Web Viewer, because Web Viewer is how other colleagues reach the report outside office.

Comment: @Anarkie, are both the cell and the data element set to the same alignment?

Comment: I made now cell1, cell2, row, column1, column2, grid, data element1, data element2 right aligned. The result is still the same.